# Web server with multiple virtual servers

Tags: nginx, server, centos, server-administration

I'm looking for a solution for the distribution of requests on port 80 on different virtual servers running VestaCP. I have a server with a permanent IP address on which the virtual server is. The illustration shows that the handling requests of the sites site7.ru site1.ru go to port 8082 of the virtual server. And when referring to site2.ru requests sent to port 8083. Please correct me if you think the idea stupid. All what i do is in order to accommodate the two hosting provider independently on a single server. As an option - the purchase of an additional IP address, but perhaps there are smarter solutions?
[image: Web server with multiple virtual servers]
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's called a load balancing and you can manage it using HAProxy or nginx, choice is yours.

So far I know VestaCP haven't nginx advanced configuration settings or HAProxy support, so you has to configure it yourself.